# Haskell - All functions of form A -> A -> ... -> A

Tags: haskell

I have a type (call it A) and I want to make a typeclass of the functions of type A -> A, A -> A -> A, A -> A -> A -> ... etc.  This doesn't work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

data A = A

class AsToA a where
  takeA :: AsToA b => a -> A -> Either A b

instance AsToA (A -> A) where
  takeA f a = Left (f a)

instance AsToA b => AsToA (A -> b) where
  takeA f a = Right (f a)
```

I get the following error message:

```
AsToA.hs:12:22:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘b1’ with actual type ‘b’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the instance declaration at AsToA.hs:11:10
      ‘b1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for

             takeA :: AsToA b1 => (A -> b) -> A -> Either A b1
          at AsToA.hs:12:3
    Relevant bindings include
      f :: A -> b (bound at AsToA.hs:12:9)
      takeA :: (A -> b) -> A -> Either A b1 (bound at AsToA.hs:12:3)
    In the first argument of ‘Right’, namely ‘(f a)’
    In the expression: Right (f a)
```

Any ideas?  Thanks very much for any advice.

Comment: I am 90% sure it's because `takeA` is implicitly existentially quantified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to the other answer, you might not really need the `Either`, and `takeA` is then basically always `id`, just with a type restriction.  If so you can make this a method-less class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

data A = A

class AsToA a

takeA :: AsToA a => a -> a
takeA = id

instance AsToA (A -> A)

instance AsToA (A -> b) => AsToA (A -> (A -> b))
```

Alternatively, you might want to convert the functions to a common type that allows you to pass in `A`s dynamically. If so `Either` won't be enough, but you can define your own:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

data A = A

data R = Result A | MoreArgs (A -> R)

class AsToA a where
    takeA :: a -> A -> R

instance AsToA (A -> A) where
    takeA f a = Result (f a)

instance AsToA (A -> b) => AsToA (A -> (A -> b)) where
    takeA f a = MoreArgs (takeA $ f a)
```

Comment: That second answer is perfect, thanks very much.  I'm sorry if I wasn't being very clear before.

Answer (score 4):

There is some confusion between the two `b`s:

```
class AsToA a where
  takeA :: AsToA b => a -> A -> Either A b

instance AsToA b => AsToA (A -> b) where
  takeA f a = Right (f a)
```

These are not the same. Let's rename the first one to `c`

```
class AsToA a where
  takeA :: AsToA c => a -> A -> Either A c

instance AsToA b => AsToA (A -> b) where
  takeA f a = Right (f a)
```

Now, `Right (f a)` has type `Either A b` but should have type `Either A c` for any `c` such that `AsToA c` holds. This does not type check.

The issue here is that the signature

```
  takeA :: AsToA c => a -> A -> Either A c
```

promises that `takeA` can return `Either A c` for *any* `c`, caller's choice. This is not what you want, I guess.

---

I'm still not sure about what the actual intended result is, but I guess the problem is similar to the following one.

> Given a function `f` of type `A->A->...->A` return a function 
>   `\x -> f x x ...`, with one application of 
>   `x` for each `->` in the type (hence of type `A->A`).

A possible solution is

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}
data A = A -- could be anything

class C f where
   takeA :: f -> A -> A

instance C (A -> A) where
   takeA f = f

instance C b => C (A -> b) where
    takeA f = \x -> takeA (f x) x
```

Note that this requires `OverlappingInstances` to be used, which is quite *evil*. I'd recommend to avoid it.

To avoid it, in this case it's enough to define an instance even for the
type `A`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
data A = A -- could be anything

class C f where
   takeA :: f -> A -> A

instance C A where
   takeA a = \_ -> a

instance C b => C (A -> b) where
    takeA f = \x -> takeA (f x) x
```

Comment: *promises that takeA can return Either A c for any c* - so essentially, it's the problem of `takeA` being declared as `forall b. AsToA b = a -> a -> Either A b`, where the `b` in the instance is rigid, right?

Comment: So what do you suggest I do?  Is it possible to define this typeclass at all?

Comment: @RhubarbAndC I am not sure what do you need that `Either` for

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Yes, exactly.

Comment: @RhubarbAndC I'm not sure what should be the result you expect. What should be the exact result type for e.g. the case `A->A->A` ? Maybe if you can show some examples without typeclasses (on fixed types), someone can craft a generalization for that.

Comment: I don't want the typeclass to include A, but it should include anything of the type (A -> A) .  takeA should return another AsToA for most instances, but has to return an A for (A -> A).  So in general it should return Either A (Something in AsToA).  If it's not possible to define takeA like this, then can anyone think of another way of defining this typeclass?

Comment: @chi Oh sorry - I want the instance for (A -> A -> A) to define takeA f a = f a, which has type (A -> A).  This then defines takeA f a = f a, which has type A.  Basically, I want a function in this class to be able to take an arbitrary number of inputs, which I will keep giving it until I get an A back.

Comment: @RhubarbAndC How would `takeA` differ from `id` (note that `id f a1 a2 .. an = f a1 a2 .. an`) ?

Comment: @chi takeA should work only on members of the class, and classify its output as either another member of the class or a value of type A.  id doesn't work this way, because I can't "type match" on a function to see how many inputs it has, can I?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92294/discussion-between-rhubarbandc-and-chi).